# How to check three character length using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.{3}$", ErrorMessage="Code should be Only three Chracter Length!")]
```

Codes needs to support all alphabet character. I need to check my string length should be three alphabetic characters, but this is not working for me.

Comment: you need to be a little clearer, i think.  do you want to check the length of a string? do you want to check the result of a regex? (etc.) it would help if you showed us some code

Comment: user957, you have four tags that start with "j".  Suggest you remove some or all of them.  I added "regex" which is prolly all that really belongs.

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net validation attribute? If so, you need to amend the tags for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Javascript regex match of exactly 3 alphabetic characters, you'd need:

```
var matchResult = myString.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{3}$/);
```